# Not able to set a value into an ADC

Tags: adc, datasheet, register

I'm trying to configure an ADC ([ADC12j4000](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/slas989c/slas989c.pdf)) and I need to configure the number of serial lanes (denoted as L in the page 39 of the datasheet). For some factors as D, DDR, P54, K... I can see how to configure them in the page 70 of the datasheet, where by some address, I can configure the ADC for the desired values. But as I mentioned before, I am not able to configure the number of lanes. Is there any other way to do it?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks for all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not configure the number of lanes. This is derived (automatically determined) based on your selections for other parameters.

Comment: Thank you! It was not at all derived by the ADC, but I had to configure it deeper (via AXI), so your comment helped me to watch at other datasheet where I could modify that value. Thanks! @glenn-w9iq